# Add Jquery UI Dialog Box to OpenLayers 3 overlay

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I'm trying to create a custom popup overlay using Openlayers 3 and Jquery UI dialog boxes. (I want use the dialog box as a popup window).

I'm a bit stuck though as my Jquery coding isn't good. I was wondering if anyone has done this already, and if so could they point me in the right direction? The code I have so far is:

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([-0.06, 51.55], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 13
    })
  });

 map.on('click', function(evt) {

        var popup = document.getElementById('popupContainer');
        popup.innerHTML= "<div id='dialogTest' style='position:relative;'>Hello</div>";
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        $(function() {
        $( "#dialogTest" ).dialog({
                   //autoOpen: false,
                  minWidth: 200,                           
                  minHeight: 200
                  position: {'within':popup}
             }
        );
        });

         var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
            element:popup

            });

          overlay.setPosition(coordinate);  

          map.addOverlay(overlay);
          popup.style.display = 'block';
              $( "#dialogTest" ).dialog( "open" );           

    });
```

Comment: If you want to consider [other options](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do a popup, but jQueryUI's dialog is pretty simple set up with OL3.

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  var $pop = $("#popup").dialog({
    minWidth: 100,
    minHeight: 100,
    position: {
      'of':  e.browserEvent.getBrowserEvent()
    }
  });

  $pop.html('<h3>clicked on <strong>'+ e.pixel +'</strong></h3>');

  map.addOverlay({
    element: $pop
  });
});
```

I think the hardest part with this is getting the positioning right.  The `of` param of the position option can take a browserEvent object.  So to get this object, we can pull it from the click event that was fired: `e.browserEvent.getBrowserEvent()`.  Pass that to the `of` and you can add more options to move it around from there.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timh06/mdkan3ss/